# How do you delete AWS Redshift Serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services

There's no button to "Stop" or "Delete" the cluster.
I managed to delete default "Workgroup" but Redshift is still running.
Any idea how to delete Redshift Serverless cluster from AWS web console?

Note:

Cannot delete using AWS CLI because it's not in list of clusters

```
aws redshift describe-clusters
{
    "Clusters": []
}
```

**Finally:**

After deleting "Workgroup" and "Namespace" and waiting for couple of hours AWS Redshift Serverless was gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to delete a cluster from the web interface. You should open support ticket for this.

You can try from command line - the first command gets the cluster identifier:

```
aws redshift describe-clusters

aws redshift delete-cluster --cluster-identifier <value>
```

Not sure how up to date is this info.

For more information about the topic check [this Q/A](https://repost.aws/questions/QU5MXx3qpQSFiI2jREAvl3_g/how-to-delete-redshift-serverless)

Comment: My free AWS account cannot use support.

Comment: @AlexB, check my updated answer

Comment: what "--cluster-identifier" ? how does it look like. there's nothing like this on RS page

Comment: `aws redshift describe-clusters` should give you the cluster ID

Comment: "describe-clusters" does not return any clusters

Comment: it disappeared finally